# Trying to Authenticate Coldfusion to FitBit API OAuth1

Tags: api, oauth, coldfusion, fitbit

This is my first oAuth1 project.  I am trying to connect to FitBit's API.  I've gone to fitbit, registered an app and recorded my key and secret.

I have then downloaded and attempted to setup:
http://oauth.riaforge.org/

1) I found that I get a connection failure when trying to connect via SSL.. but I think that is a keystore issue.  When I go back to http it at least attempts a connection:

2) I am currently using the code from the examples_external/google.cfm file.  It seemed to be the closest match.

When I run the code, I receive the response noted below.  I am assuming that the oauth client sends the link over as a get with all the values in the URL, and Fitbit wants a POST and it wants an Authentication Header.  I've researched as far as I can get but CF examples with Fitbit and Oauth are lacking.

Here is what they are looking for.
https://wiki.fitbit.com/display/API/OAuth+Authentication+in+the+Fitbit+API

Any guidance would be appreciated.

```
<!--- set up the parameters --->
<cfset sConsumerKey = "xxxxx"> <!--- FromFit Bit  --->
<cfset sConsumerSecret = "yyyy"> <!--- From FitBit --->
<cfset sTokenEndpoint = "http://api.fitbit.com/oauth/request_token"> <!--- Access Token URL --->
<cfset sAuthorizationEndpoint = "http://www.fitbit.com/oauth/authorize"> <!--- Authorize URL --->
<cfset sCallbackURL = "http://www.example.com/fitbit/callback.cfm"> <!--- where fitbit will redirect to after the user enters their details --->
<cfset sClientToken = ""> <!--- returned after an access token call --->
<cfset sClientTokenSecret = ""> <!--- returned after an access token call --->
<cfset sScope =''> <!--- required for google --->

<!--- set up the required objects including signature method--->
<cfset oReqSigMethodSHA = CreateObject("component", "oauth.oauthsignaturemethod_hmac_sha1")>
<cfset oToken = CreateObject("component", "oauth.oauthtoken").createEmptyToken()>
<cfset oConsumer = CreateObject("component", "oauth.oauthconsumer").init(sKey = sConsumerKey, sSecret = sConsumerSecret)>

<cfset Parameters = structNew()>
<cfset parameters.scope = sScope>

<cfset oReq = CreateObject("component", "oauth.oauthrequest").fromConsumerAndToken(
    oConsumer = oConsumer,
    oToken = oToken,
    sHttpMethod = "GET",
    sHttpURL = sTokenEndpoint,stparameters=Parameters )>

<cfset oReq.signRequest(
    oSignatureMethod = oReqSigMethodSHA,
    oConsumer = oConsumer,
    oToken = oToken)>


<cfhttp url="#oREQ.getString()#" method="get" result="tokenResponse"/>

<!--- grab the token and secret from the response if its there--->
<cfif findNoCase("oauth_token",tokenresponse.filecontent)>
    <cfset sClientToken = listlast(listfirst(tokenResponse.filecontent,"&"),"=")>
    <cfset sClientTokenSecret = listlast(listlast(tokenResponse.filecontent,"&"),"=")>

    <!--- you can add some additional parameters to the callback --->
    <cfset sCallbackURL = sCallbackURL & "?" &
        "key=" & sConsumerKey &
        "&" & "secret=" & sConsumerSecret &
        "&" & "token=" & sClientToken &
        "&" & "token_secret=" & sClientTokenSecret &
        "&" & "endpoint=" & URLEncodedFormat(sAuthorizationEndpoint)>

    <cfset sAuthURL = sAuthorizationEndpoint & "?oauth_token=" & sClientToken & "&" & "oauth_callback=" & URLEncodedFormat(sCallbackURL) >

    <cflocation url="#sAuthURL#">

<cfelse>
    <cfoutput>#tokenResponse.filecontent#</cfoutput>
</cfif>
```

Returns

```
{"errors":[{"errorType":"oauth","fieldName":"n/a","message":"No Authorization header provided in the request. Each call to Fitbit API should be OAuth signed"}],"success":false}
```

**UPDATE:** I was able to get a little bit further with an example I found for someone connecting to linkedin with a similar issue....  updated code:

```
<!--- set up the parameters --->
<cfset sConsumerKey = "xxxxx"> <!--- FromFit Bit  --->
<cfset sConsumerSecret = "xxxxxxxx"> <!--- From FitBit --->
<cfset sTokenEndpoint = "http://api.fitbit.com/oauth/request_token"> <!--- Access Token URL --->
<cfset sAuthorizationEndpoint = "http://api.fitbit.com/oauth/authorize"> <!--- Authorize URL --->
<cfset sCallbackURL = "http://www.example.com/fitbit/callback.cfm"> <!--- where fitbit will redirect to after the user enters their details --->
<cfset sClientToken = ""> <!--- returned after an access token call --->
<cfset sClientTokenSecret = ""> <!--- returned after an access token call --->


<!--- set up the required objects including signature method--->
<cfset oReqSigMethodSHA = CreateObject("component", "oauth.oauthsignaturemethod_hmac_sha1")>
<cfset oToken = CreateObject("component", "oauth.oauthtoken").createEmptyToken()>
<cfset oConsumer = CreateObject("component", "oauth.oauthconsumer").init(sKey = sConsumerKey, sSecret = sConsumerSecret)>

<cfset Parameters = structNew()>

<cfset oReq = CreateObject("component", "oauth.oauthrequest").fromConsumerAndToken(
    oConsumer = oConsumer,
    oToken = oToken,
    sHttpMethod = "POST",
    sHttpURL = sTokenEndpoint,stparameters=Parameters )>

<cfset oReq.signRequest(
    oSignatureMethod = oReqSigMethodSHA,
    oConsumer = oConsumer,
    oToken = oToken)>


<cfhttp url="#oReq.GETNORMALIZEDHTTPURL()#" method="post" result="tokenresponse">
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Authorization" value="#oReq.TOHEADER()#" />
</cfhttp>

<!--- 
FROM HERE DOWN IS ALL FROM EXAMPLE FILE

grab the token and secret from the response if its there--->
<cfif findNoCase("oauth_token",tokenresponse.filecontent)>
    <cfset sClientToken = listlast(listfirst(tokenResponse.filecontent,"&"),"=")>
    <cfset sClientTokenSecret = listlast(listlast(tokenResponse.filecontent,"&"),"=")>

    <!--- you can add some additional parameters to the callback --->
    <cfset sCallbackURL = sCallbackURL & "?" &
        "key=" & sConsumerKey &
        "&" & "secret=" & sConsumerSecret &
        "&" & "token=" & sClientToken &
        "&" & "token_secret=" & sClientTokenSecret &
        "&" & "endpoint=" & URLEncodedFormat(sAuthorizationEndpoint)>

    <cfset sAuthURL = sAuthorizationEndpoint & "?oauth_token=" & sClientToken & "&" & "oauth_callback=" & URLEncodedFormat(sCallbackURL) >

    <cflocation url="#sAuthURL#">

<cfelse>
    <cfoutput>#tokenResponse.filecontent#</cfoutput>
</cfif>
```

However, now I am at the callback.... I thought it would look similar but just appending 2 values, but I can't seem to append it correctly.

```
<cfset sConsumerKey = ""> <!--- FromFit Bit  --->
<cfset sConsumerSecret = ""> <!--- From FitBit --->
<cfset sTokenEndpoint = "http://api.fitbit.com/oauth/request_token"> <!--- Access Token URL --->
<cfset sAuthorizationEndpoint = "http://api.fitbit.com/oauth/authorize"> <!--- Authorize URL --->
<cfset sCallbackURL = "http://www.example.com/fitbit/callback.cfm"> <!--- where fitbit will redirect to after the user enters their details --->
<cfset sClientToken = "#url.oauth_token#"> <!--- returned after an access token call --->
<cfset sClientTokenSecret = "#url.oauth_verifier#"> <!--- returned after an access token call --->


<!--- set up the required objects including signature method--->
<cfset oReqSigMethodSHA = CreateObject("component", "oauth.oauthsignaturemethod_hmac_sha1")>
<cfset oToken = CreateObject("component", "oauth.oauthtoken").createEmptyToken()>
<cfset oConsumer = CreateObject("component", "oauth.oauthconsumer").init(sKey = sConsumerKey, sSecret = sConsumerSecret)>

<cfset Parameters = structNew()>
<cfset parameters.oauth_token=url.oauth_token>
<cfset parameters.oauth_verifier=url.oauth_verifier>

<cfset oReq = CreateObject("component", "oauth.oauthrequest").fromConsumerAndToken(
    oConsumer = oConsumer,
    oToken = oToken,
    sHttpMethod = "POST",
    sHttpURL = sTokenEndpoint,stparameters=Parameters )>

<cfset oReq.signRequest(
    oSignatureMethod = oReqSigMethodSHA,
    oConsumer = oConsumer,
    oToken = oToken)>

Header:<Cfdump var="#oreq.toheader()#"><br>


<cfhttp url="http://api.fitbit.com/oauth/access_token" method="post" result="tokenresponse">
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Authorization" value="#oReq.TOHEADER()#" />
</cfhttp>
```

I'm returning the following error:

```
{"errors":[{"errorType":"oauth","fieldName":"oauth_access_token","message":"Invalid signature or token 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' or token 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'"}],"success":false}
```

which seems to be because the verifier and token aren't showing up inside the header (or anywhere)...

So basically I think a good oauth callback file example would get me on track.

Comment: In the update, what seemed to work was 1) the updated cfhttp call and 2) taking out the scope or leaving it blank.  This fixed the No Authorization header issue and forwarded the user to fitbit to login and allow my application.  Now I am stuck with sending their client token and verifier back to fitbit from the callback page to get the official token.

Answer (score 1):

*Let me preface this by saying that I have not worked with the FitBit API.*  From the error you are receiving and from the link you provided, the API requires authorization headers to be included in the request. Below is an example of how to include HTTP headers in your ColdFusion `cfhttp` call.

The API documentation that you referenced mentions that the following authorization header parameters are required for the Request:

> - oauth_callback - Callback URL. The server stores this URL and redirects to it later when user authorizes client.
> - oauth_consumer_key - The client key agreed upon at registration.
> - oauth_nonce - Random string uniquely generated by client to allow the server to verify uniqueness of request.
> - oauth_signature - Signature calculated as described in The OAuth 1.0 Protocol Section 3.4: Signature.
> - oauth_signature_method - Signature method: HMAC-SHA1
> - oauth_timestamp - Timestamp
> - oauth_version - 1.0

From their example your ColdFusion code would look something like this:

```
<cfhttp url="#oREQ.getString()#" method="get" result="tokenResponse">
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="oauth_callback" value="http%3A%2F%2Fexample.fitbit.com%2Fapp%2FcompleteAuthorization" />
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="oauth_consumer_key" value="fitbit-example-client-application" />
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="oauth_nonce" value="161822064" />
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="oauth_signature" value="Omf%2Bls2gn%2BDlghq245LRIyfMdd8%3D" />
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="oauth_signature_method" value="HMAC-SHA1" />
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="oauth_timestamp" value="1270248082" />
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="oauth_version" value="1.0" />
</cfhttp>
```

Hopefully this is enough to get you a little further.

*Update*
I did come across some [other oauth examples](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5568425/1636917) that passed the parameters a bit differently. Here is an example of that approach if the previous does not work:

```
<cfhttp url="#oREQ.getString()#" method="get" result="tokenResponse">
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="content-type" value="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
    <cfhttpparam type="oauth_callback" name="FormField" value="http%3A%2F%2Fexample.fitbit.com%2Fapp%2FcompleteAuthorization" />
    <cfhttpparam type="oauth_consumer_key" name="FormField" value="fitbit-example-client-application" />
    <cfhttpparam type="oauth_nonce" name="FormField" value="161822064" />
    <cfhttpparam type="oauth_signature" name="FormField" value="Omf%2Bls2gn%2BDlghq245LRIyfMdd8%3D" />
    <cfhttpparam type="oauth_signature_method" name="FormField" value="HMAC-SHA1" />
    <cfhttpparam type="oauth_timestamp" name="FormField" value="1270248082" />
    <cfhttpparam type="oauth_version" name="FormField" value="1.0" />
</cfhttp>
```

Comment: thanks for taking the time.  I've seen a lot of those examples, for for me, they didnt seem to work.  I did progress a little further on my project.  The key thing that I was unable to do is use the Oauth library to isolate each of those values into their own variable to send them seperately.  If I was able to, it would probably help me with my callback issue. - I updated the question to reflect what is working for me.

Comment: @steve did you happen to come across Ben Nadel's blog? He always has excellent examples and I may have found one for you. [Saturday Hackathon: Integrating Twitter, oAuth, Twilio, And ColdFusion](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2022-saturday-hackathon-integrating-twitter-oauth-twilio-and-coldfusion.htm). In it he "_was able to distill oAuth down to just two ColdFusion components - OAuthService.cfc and OAuthRequest.cfc. These components deal very narrowly with oAuth and know nothing about Twitter itself._" From that page you can download his cfcs for more oauth examples.

Comment: thanks.  I saw the blog but missed the code examples... just saw the links to other blogs at the bottom.  I'll check that out.  I'm very surprised that oauth1 is so much more complicated than oauth2.

Comment: but I believe that was some of the thinking behind oauth2 - to make things easier.  ;)

Comment: I made an attempt at using Ben's project as a sample and got to the same place that I had made it to.  I don't quite understand oauth that well since this is my 2nd project but it seems that when you get the access token you have to make a new signature based off the token in the call back and encrypt it again, and thats where I am getting messed up on.. it seems to be different.  I've spent too many hours on it so I just put an odesk project out there to see if someone can play around with it for me.